# Checked List Box Specific item Checked When Double click DataGridView On Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i am using CheckedListBox so that user can multi select items for this i am populating CheckedListBox dynamically from database Here is CheckedListBox Filling Method

```
     public void FillSubjectsCombo()
      {
        DataTable dt = objSubCls.FillSubjects();
        chkLstBxClass_FrmSubjecClassRelation.DataSource = dt;
        chkLstBxClass_FrmSubjecClassRelation.DisplayMember = "Subjects";
        chkLstBxClass_FrmSubjecClassRelation.ValueMember = "SubId";
        chkLstBxClass_FrmSubjecClassRelation.Enabled = true;

          for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
          {
            //Here i am setting Every item Checked
            chkLstBxClass_FrmSubjecClassRelation.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Checked);
          }
      }
```

On the Same Windows Form I have DataGridView i Want when i double click any row of datagrid then from selected row get value and from that value make respected item checked in CheckedListBox and other item UnChecked

Here is the DataGridView Event

```
 private void dgv_FrmSubjectClassRelation_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string classId = dgv_FrmSubjectClassRelation.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        string className = dgv_FrmSubjectClassRelation.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        foreach (int i in chkLstBxClass_FrmSubjecClassRelation.CheckedIndices)
        {
               //Here I am UnChecking Every Checked Item 
            chkLstBxClass_FrmSubjecClassRelation.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked);
        }
```

My Question : How to Checked The Specific Item When Double Clicking DataGridView

Update:  I am binding My DataGridView Like This

```
  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dgv_FrmSmstrClsAssign.Rows.Add();
                dgv_FrmSmstrClsAssign.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0];//Acadmc Yr
                dgv_FrmSmstrClsAssign.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1];// Semester Name
                dgv_FrmSmstrClsAssign.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2]; //College 
                dgv_FrmSmstrClsAssign.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[3];//Class

                dgv_FrmSmstrClsAssign.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[4]; //Entry Date
                dgv_FrmSmstrClsAssign.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[5];//IsActive
                dgv_FrmSmstrClsAssign.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[6];//AcadmicYr Id
                dgv_FrmSmstrClsAssign.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[7];//Semster Id
                dgv_FrmSmstrClsAssign.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[8];//Semster Id

            }
```

Comment: `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` has property `RowIndex`. Have you tried to get checkbox id using this index?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109675/checkedlistbox-search-for-an-item-by-text) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111558/get-index-with-value-in-checked-list-box) to find items in some listbox. Of course it is up to you to know just what the relation of the values in the two controls resp. the DataTable is: Is the `classId ` the same as `SubId`..??

Comment: No .... i am not having any problem with DataGridView I want to Set Specific item of  CheckedListBox Checked......

Comment: Does the DataTable have some primary key(or another unique value) that can allow easy identification of rows?

Comment: Yes i have primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find any method that allows you to easily map the bound value, so you will have to use [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) method of [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx) collection to obtain the index and then manually check-uncheck the items.

To obtain the bound item from `DataGridView` row you can use [DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
private void CheckSelectedItem()
{
    // Get bound item object from datagrid
    object item = dgv_FrmSubjectClassRelation.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

    // Get corresponding index in listView
    Int32 itemIndexInCheckedListView = chkLstBxClass_FrmSubjecClassRelation.Items.IndexOf(item);

    // Check the item in listView
    chkLstBxClass_FrmSubjecClassRelation.SetItemCheckState(itemIndexInCheckedListView,
          CheckState.Checked);
}

private void dgv_FrmSubjectClassRelation_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string classId = dgv_FrmSubjectClassRelation.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    string className = dgv_FrmSubjectClassRelation.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

    foreach (int i in chkLstBxClass_FrmSubjecClassRelation.CheckedIndices)
    {
        //Here I am UnChecking Every Checked Item 
        chkLstBxClass_FrmSubjecClassRelation.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked);
    }

    // --------------Check the selected item----------------
    this.CheckSelectedItem();
}
```

**EDIT:**

What you do is not exactly binding (well, it is binding, just not as [Windows Forms defines it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.90).)), so the previous solution won't work for you. If both your DataTable and DataGridView contain primary key or another unique identifier, then it is possible to map CurrentRow to the Item in DataTable:

```
private void CheckSelectedItem()
{
    // Get bound item object from datagrid
    object uniqueKey = dgv_FrmSubjectClassRelation.
        CurrentRow.
        Cells["SOME UNIQUE VALUE COLUMN"].
        Value;

    // Adapting http://stackoverflow.com/a/9300237/3745022 - there are more simple LINQless 
    // solutions for this situation, but it is not important for the concept.
    Int32 itemIndexInCheckedListView = chkLstBxClass_FrmSubjecClassRelation.
        Items.
        Select((value, index) => new { value, index }).
        Where(pair => pair.value.UniqueValue == uniqueKey ).
        Select(pair => pair.index + 1).
        FirstOrDefault() - 1;

    // Check the item in listView
    chkLstBxClass_FrmSubjecClassRelation.SetItemCheckState(itemIndexInCheckedListView,
          CheckState.Checked);
}
```

If you do not have such Unique column you may want to add it(just make it hidden)

**OR** even better - use full-blown DataBinding - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.90).aspx;

Comment: object item = dgv_FrmSubjectClassRelation.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem; it giving me null value

Comment: @KhurramAli Hmm, do you bind the data to the datagridview or you add it manually? Or maybe it is CurrentRow is null(it is hardly possible, but nonetheless)?

Comment: i am accepting Your answer because i have solve my question similar to your asnswer .....Thmkxxx